# JSON for List of int

Tags: json

I have a class

```
public class ItemList
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<int> ItemModList { get; set; }
}
```

how should i give the input JSON for list of int as it does not have a key to match its value

JSON

```
{
    "Id": "610",
    "Name": "15",
    "Description": "1.99",
    "ItemModList": []
}
```

what should I write in the ItemModList

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Assuming your ints are 0, 375, 668,5 and 6:

```
{
    "Id": "610",
    "Name": "15",
    "Description": "1.99",
    "ItemModList": [
                       0,
                       375,
                       668,
                       5,
                       6
                   ]
}
```

I suggest that you change "Id": "610" to "Id": 610 since it is a integer/long and not a string. You can read more about the JSON format and examples here http://json.org/

Answer (score 22):

JSON is perfectly capable of expressing lists of integers, and the JSON you have posted is valid. You can simply separate the integers by commas:

```
{
    "Id": "610",
    "Name": "15",
    "Description": "1.99",
    "ItemModList": [42, 47, 139]
}
```

Comment: @RonKalian Huh? This question is not really about Python. The code sample looks like C#. Plus, Python's default parser will create lists; try `import json;print(type(json.loads('[42, 47, 139]')))`