# Swagger 2,0 query parameter syntax for a list or array of integers

Tags: api, swagger, query-string

I have been wrecking my brain reading docs and trying to successfully pass through a list or an array of integers using swagger because I am trying to test my API.

I am trying to pass through a list of teamIDs like this: (I've been trying all kinds of variations, mind you) but the values are still not pulling through when I debug

```
 {
"type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "integer",
        "enum": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
   }
```

I am using "enum" because its a list of values I am trying to pass through.

Here is a screenshot of my swagger method as well:

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114503/json-for-list-of-int if that helps

Answer (score 1):

A query parameter that is an array of integers is defined as follows:

```json
{
  "in: query",
  "name": "teamIDs",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "integer"
  }
}
```

In your Swagger UI, enter the values for the `teamIDs` parameter **one per line**, like so:

```
1
2
3
```